# Move a specific string element at the end of substring lists

Tags: r, substring

I have a string like

> 'a,x,y,b;x,b'

Now I would like to move a specific string, like `x`, at the end of each substring, keeping the order of the other elements the same, so that result would look like:

> 'a,y,b,x;b,x'

In order to achieve the result, I first tried to split the string using semicolon (`;`) into substrings

```
> unlist(strsplit('a,x,b,y;x,b',';'))
[1] "a,x,b,y" "x,b"
```

And then again split the substrings using comma (`;`) to string elements:

```
> strsplit(unlist(strsplit('x,b,y;x,b',';')),',')
[[1]]
[1] "a" "x" "b" "y"

[[2]]
[1] "x" "b"
```

But how should I move element `"x"` at the end of each substring, and then combine again the strings to the desired result `'a,y,b,x;b,x'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the string, extract the element which is x, take all elements which are not x and put the x at the end of that. Then paste everything together.

```
x <- strsplit(unlist(strsplit('x,b,y;x,b',';')),',')
x_end <- lapply(x, function(x1) paste(c(x1[x1 != "x"], x1[x1 == "x"]), collapse = ","))
paste(unlist(x_end), collapse = ";")
```